# How to "create" a Map literal in Esper?

Tags: esper

If I have an event type that has a column of type java.util.Map, how can I in EPL create a literal for use in an INSERT, to achieve something like:

```
insert into Event(id,myMap) select 1 as id, {'A':2,'B':3};
```

I know this is the right syntax or even if there is one for what I want to achieve. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the "new" keyword. The documentation link is [new](http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.1.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#epl-operator-new).

Alternative is writing a UDF or script.